# How to initialize DbContext from child project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generic-programming

I have two web project, first is **framework** and other is **shopping**, both of projects are WebForm and i'm using Entity Framework.
i want to implement `GenericRepository` in framework project and then use it in shopping project.
framework project has it's own `DbContext` named `FrameworkContext` and shopping project has it's own `DbContext` thats extends `FrameworkContext` and named `AppContext`.

```
public class FrameworkContext : DbContext
{
    public FrameworkContext() : base("name=AppContext")
    {
    }
}

public class AppContext : FrameworkContext
{
    public AppContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Car> cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Plaque> plaques { get; set; }
}


public class GenericRepository<T, Key> : IGenericRepository<T, Key> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private FrameworkContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
    }

    public FrameworkContext context
    {
        get { return _dbContext; }
        set { _dbContext = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> getAll()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

**web.config of shopping project**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=ASUS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testFramework;Integrated Security=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

now, i add framework project as a reference to shopping project. when i call `getAll()` method of `Repository` this below exception is thrown:

[image]

**UPDATE**

i'm used from @octavioccl's solution to solve my problems. now another exception occurred:
[image]

and these are my `BaseEntity` class and `Car` class:

```
namespace framework.Model
{
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 id { get; set; }

        public string createdDate { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace shopping.model
{
    public class Car : BaseEntity
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Plaque> plaques { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you initialize your `dbContext` variable on your `GenericRepository` class, try initializing this variable in the constructor:

```
 public GenericRepository()
{
 _dbContext=new FrameworkContext();
}
```

### Update

Well there are many ways to solve your second exception, the problem is because your context doesn't know about your entity:

A solution could be declaring a property on your context as follow:

```
public DbSet<Car> Cars{get;set;}
```

Or using Fluent Api, for example, overriding `OnModelCreating` method and doing something like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasKey(c=>c.Id);
```

But the best way is create a mapping class for each entity:

```
public class CarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
```

An later you only need to do this in your `OnModelCreating` method to discover all the mappings:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(FrameworkContext).Assembly);// set here the asembly where there are all your mapping classes.
 }
```

Comment: now, the exception changed to this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8npWo6XrlQ-dWVvVFRRY0VKem8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I do not want to declare properties in `FrameworkContext`, because it is a framework that can be used in other project, and each project should have it's own entity. as you seen above, i declare `cars` in `AppContext`, the framework is only to centralize methods and  behaviors.

Comment: use the last variant, is the best for your design

Comment: And what type are you using to create a generic repository, `BaseEntity`? If that is the case you can't do that, do it only with the derived types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105047/discussion-between-rasool-ghafari-and-octavioccl).